Evaluating the Impact of Subject Combinations on Student Failure: Probabilistic Approach
i have students academic data and would like to investigate whether some subject combinations will increase the probability of failure.
let's make an example data set (data sourced from real uni data cannot be shared):
idx student subject fail_or_not
1   A       1       1
2   A       2       0
3   A       3       1
4   B       1       0
5   B       2       1
6   C       1       0

(e.g student A took subject 1 and 2 at the same time and failed in 1 and 3...)
if im gonna calculate the prob of failure for combinated subj 1 and 2.
so im thinking i can simply take the average of fail_or_not for all the records that the students took subj 1 and 2, which is from student A and B, after taking average(from idx 1,2,4,5), the answer is 0.5.
but student A also take the subj 3, i think i probly miss the interactions from subj 3, i think all the data from students A shouldn't be considered separately. maybe it will be better if i also take idx 3 into calculation? the answer then is 0.6, which means all the results from the students will be comptered. is it more reasonable?
then i talked to chatgpt, chat gives me more insights that i can use condistional probobilities or building a model to solve. it's getting to a very complicated probability problem.. can anyone give me a explicit direction? im confused to how can i evaluate which method makes more sense.

Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, when all the variables involved are discrete, the probability distribution can be summarized as a simple table. It might be a large table if there are many combinations, but it will be a table. Your research question about whether combinations of classes are associated with failure rate is just whether you can factor the full table, indexed by all variables, into smaller tables, indexed by one or a smaller number of variables.

thank you, apologize for posting in the wrong place, I will switch to stats one.

No problem, just trying to steer you in the direction of a more suitable audience.

Though I'm not good at statistics, but let me answer.
Hope you find some insights from my answer.
Your requirement here is to "investigate whether some subject combinations will increase the probability of failure."
I think, if the dataset is fixed, the probability of failure of each subject combinations is also fixed. For example, in the dataset above:
idx student subject fail_or_not
1   A       1       1
2   A       2       0
3   A       3       1
4   B       1       0
5   B       2       1
6   C       1       0

combination  failure rate  # of cases
∅            N/A           0
{1}          0.5           2
{2}          0.5           2 
{3}          1.0           1
{1,2}        0.5           2
{1,3}        1.0           1
{2,3}        0.5           1
{1,2,3}      0.667         1

combination ∅: There are no students who did not take any subject, so skip the combination ∅.
combination {1}: There are 2 students(A, B) who took subject 1. Student A failed the subject but student B did not failed the subject, so the failure rate = 1/2 = 0.5.
...
combination {1,2}: There are 2 students(A, B) who took subject 1 and 2, at the same time. In this case, both students failed 1 subject and passed 1 subject, so the failure rate = 2/4 = 0.5.

Like this, you can find whether some subject combinations will increase the probability of failure, or not.
I think problem by far is not very difficult.

But, suppose that you were planning to take subject {1,2} and you wonder whether taking additional subject 3, or not taking subject 1 will increase/decrease the probability of your failure.
In this case, I think the problem becomes very treaky, because there are more things that should be considered.
For example, if you are a freshman and the subject 3 is too difficult for you to take because of the lack of background knowledge of your field, your probability of failure is likely to increase. However, if you are a senior and the subject is very easy for you, your probability of failure is likely to decrease.
And you have to consider that: The less the number of subjects a student take, the more the impact that an individual failure of subject affects to the overral failure rate.
And the lack of cases should be considered, for example:
combination  failure rate  # of cases
{1,2}        0.48          2736
{1,2,3}      0.46          12

Taking additional subject 3 lowers the failure rate, but you cannot say that taking additional subject 3 is always better because there are not sufficient historical cases.
In summary, There are many additional factors to be considered, so I think the dataset (student, subject, fail_or_not) is not enough to solve the latter problem. If so, I think you have to get more columns to your dataset and run a machine learning model.

Simple: compute all possible subject combinations, if you have n subjects, then you have 2^n combinations (except for the trivial combination of having no subjects), loop through them (if you think the combination as a binary number whose each digit is a subject that was either chosen or not) and find all matches (i.e., people who had the exact combination) and compute the average success/failure for each. Sort the combinations via success rate ascendingly or descendingly, depending on your preference and you are done.
